# Why is there no console log for this mongoose code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to learn how to utilize mongoDB with connection open and I came across Mongoose.

I tried to test my connection to mongoDB with mongoose and it worked.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = "mongodb://IP:port/database";
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true },function(err){console.log("Connected")});
```

My MongoDB is in following structure:

Database name : db

Collection name : myCollection

Document structure in Collection: `{_id:'random object string generated by mongoDB, name: 'Name', bill: '56445'}`

I wanted to get all the documents or matching documents, like, `db.myCollection.find()` or `db.myCollection.find({name:'Jeeva'})`

Here's what I tried:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = "mongodb://IP:port/db";
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var myCollection = new Schema({
    name : String,
    bill : String
}, {collections : 'myCollection'});
var myCollectionModel = mongoose.model('myCollection', myCollection);
var myCollection = mongoose.model('myCollection')
myCollection.find({}, function(error, PO){
    console.log("im here!")
    console.log(PO);    
});
```

Console:

```
im here!
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is with your model. Its trying to find documents in **myCollections** i.e the plural of the first parameter you pass to model creation method. This is the default behavior of mongoose. To deal with you can manually pass your collection name as the third param. Try changing

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = "mongodb://IP:port/db";
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var myCollection = new Schema({
    name: String,
    bill: String
}, {
    collections: 'myCollection'
});
var myCollectionModel = mongoose.model('myCollection', myCollection, 'myCollection');
myCollectionModel.find({}, function(error, PO) {
    console.log("im here!")
    console.log(PO);
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The code works! I am little confused with this: Its trying to find documents in myCollections i.e the plural of the first parameter you pass to model creation method. Are the words converted to it's plural or it is just appending 's' at the end? For example: If the first paramter is 'Is', does it change to 'Are' or Iss'?

Comment: As far as i know it will just append a 's' at the end of the first parameter. Glad it help..Happy coding :)